# Constraint layout buttons always centered

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I try to center my buttons in relation to the horizontal but one of the two buttons is not always visible and I do not find how to make the other button correctly centered horizontally. Here's what I currently have:

**When the last button is visible**

[image: When the last button is visible]

**When the last button is gone**

[image: When the last button is gone]

What I would like is that the red button is aligned under the black when the blue button is gone

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a guideline in percentage to 50% and constrain both button (second row) to it. [View example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZTMW.png)

After you hide the blue button you can move the guideline using code:

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) 
guideline.getLayoutParams();
lp.guidePercent = 100;
guideline.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Hope, it helps!